# Running two DataGridViews in a foreach loop that needs to run line by line

Tags: c#, foreach, datagridview

I have two DataGrids(Documentos and OCR) and i need to run both of them inside a foreach loop that is activated when the Importar(Import) button is pressed and i need to have them run both of those grids line by line. How can i do that? And what do i put inside the foreach().

```
switch (TabControl.SelectedTab.Name)
        {
            case "Clientes":

                
                foreach ()
                {
                    DataTable dataTableDocs = (DataTable)dataGridViewDocumentos.DataSource;

                }

                ;
                break;

            case "2":
                Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                break;
        }


    }
```

This is my btn_Import event

And these are my two DataGrids

```
private void FillDGVDocs1(int JobID, int Status)
    {

        int DocID;
        int BatchID;
        dataGridViewDocumentos.DataSource = null;
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns.Clear();
        dataGridViewDocumentos.Refresh();
        DataTable dt = da.SP_SELECT_DOCS_WHERE_JOBID_STATUS_IBML1 (JobID, Status);
        dataGridViewDocumentos.DataSource = dt;

        //dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Caixa";
        //dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[2].HeaderText = "DOC";
        //dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[3].HeaderText = "ID";
        //dataGridViewDocumentos.Columns[4].HeaderText = "PROC";

        DocID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["DocID"].ToString());
        BatchID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["BatchID"].ToString());
        FillDGVOCR(DocID, BatchID);

    }
```

Comment: What i meant to say is a foreach loop that runs one datagrid and then inside that since that the OCR datagrid is run by the information of the first one so its like one foreach loop inside another

Comment: I made it work ill post a answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it

first is with the foreach cycle

```
foreach(DataRow NameOfDataRow1 in dataGridView1){
 
 foreach(DataRow NameOfDataRow2 in dataGridView2){


}

}
```

Comment: @JohnG it was just an example but thanks ill edit it